# I've upgraded my iPhone 4S to iOS8 and now the GPS is always on

Tags: gps, google-maps, ios

I have determined that its Google Maps that is causing the GPS to be always on. Is there a way to select an option so that Google Maps only uses the GPS when the app is being used? The only options I see in Privacy > Location Services for Google Maps are "Always" or "Never".

In the meantime I've reverted to Apple Maps and deleted Google Maps to save my battery.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Google Maps will continue to use GPS in the background if the app is still running. But once you actually **closed the app** the GPS signal should be removed immediately. Have you tried closing it (using double-click on the Home button and swiping up the app to close it) to see if that works?

Comment: I have tried closing the app but it was still using the GPS. The only thing that stopped it using the GPS was too uninstall the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try updating your app? In my version, it has "Never" and "While using the app" options under location settings.

Comment: I have an iPhone 6 now and these options are present. As I dont have an iPhone 4S anymore I cant comment on the settings on that phone. Thanks, I'm back to using Google Maps.

Answer (score -1):

Try disabling Locate on Google Wallet if you are not using it, that did the trick for me.

Answer (score -3):

You can disable GPs by Following Steps:-

Step #1. Tap on Setting

Step #2. Tap on Privacy

Step #3. Tap on Location Services

Step #4. Tap on System Services

Step #5. Switch off services that you don’t use.

For More Information [How To Fix It Location Services Always On In iOS 8](http://www.igeeksblog.com/location-services-always-on-in-ios-8/)

Comment: I would want to use GPS in the maps app, but ONLY when the app is open. Disabling GPS is not an option for me.

Comment: Kindly Go Through the Post How To Fix It Location Services Always On In iOS 8 in that they have clearly mention all things.